# Adding rows from one table to another existing table where primary key is autogenerated

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho

I have two tables say Table1(`id`,`name`) and Table2 with (`id`,`name`).

Table1 looks like:

```
id    name
 1     ABC
 2     DEF
```

Table2 looks like:

```
id    name
 1    XYZ
 2    ASD
```

Can someone shed light on how I can add Table2 rows to Table1 i.e.

Table1 must finally look like:

```
id  name
 1   ABC
 2   DEF
 3   XYZ
 4   ASD
```

Comment: id in `Table 1 ` is `auto_increment` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into table1 (name) 
Select  name from table2
```

Comment: For this `id` should be AI.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, If `id` in `table1` is not `auto_increment`

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | ABC  |
|    2 | DEF  |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM table2;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | PQR  |
|    2 | XYZ  |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT MAX(id) INTO @row FROM table1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

INSERT INTO table1 SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, name FROM table2;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM table1;
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | ABC  |
|    2 | DEF  |
|    3 | PQR  |
|    4 | XYZ  |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate duplicities:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (name) 
  SELECT name 
  FROM table2 t2 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.name = t2.name )
```